# Disallow shutdown/sleep/restart on OSX?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, sleep, shutdown, hibernate

Is it possible to disable shutdown, sleep and restart for non-admin user on Mac OS X? (I am running Snow Leopard.)

Comment: Don't think so, actually

Comment: This looks like a dangerous hack, but it might work. (Be sure to back up all the relevant files before trying it...) http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040306121548561